# Commitment control error on iSeries procedure call

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, rpg

I have an intermittent problem when calling an iSeries stored procedure (consisting of various CL & RPG programs). The error is:-

```
 Commitment definition *N not valid for open of QAOSSI12
    Error occurred while opening file QAOSSI12.
```

As mentioned the problem does not always occur but occurs more when load testing the procedure.

I know the information is vague but any ideas appreciated!!

Comment: How are you loadtesting? From the outside (e.g. JDBC call), or from the inside (e.g. straight call from the procedure). In the later case, check if you use named activationgroups. As Danny T writes, check your scope.

Answer (score 0):

If this is error CPF4326, the message text gives the following possibilities:

- Member QAOSSI12 was opened for commitment control when commitment definition *N was not active.
- Uncommitted changes are pending for member QAOSSI12 for a commitment definition other than *N.
- The calling program is using commitment definition *N which has a scope of *ACTGRP, while the program specified to open the file using ascope of *JOB.

Are these situations possibles in your case?

Answer (score 0):

We've been getting CPF4326 and the solution that seems to be working is to add "transaction isolation=none" to our jdbc URL.  We aren't trying to use transactions anyway, so there's no benefit to having them enabled.  We're also suspicious that something in iBATIS is trying to rollback the transaction when there is an error, even though we don't do anything explicit as far as commitment control.

Answer (score 0):

You can change COMMIT  value at compile time to COMMIT(*NONE) then no commitment definition is created .

The Commit (COMMIT) command is used to complete the current transaction and to establish a new commitment boundary for the commitment definition associated with the program issuing the command.

You have to check also if your file in under Journal.